# Why is running raw SQL in Rails via ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute taking 10X longer than same SQL run in client or stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

I'm working in Rails and executing raw SQL to create and manage a table of temporary data for a nightly batch process. I'm planning on getting all the raw statements of the process into Stored Procedures eventually, but I'm just using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` to save some time during development and testing. Or so I thought.

This SQL statement in my client (DBeaver) runs in under 5 seconds:

```
UPDATE tmp_reporting_sales_ia 
SET reporting_license_type = NULL,
    reporting_residency = 'N'
;
# Updated Rows  1304030
```

(**Note**: if I `RESET QUERY CACHE;` before running the statement, same results)

However, if I run that same statement via the ActiveRecord connection, it takes over 50 seconds.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE tmp_reporting_sales_ia SET reporting_license_type = NULL, reporting_residency = 'N';")
D, [2022-12-07T22:16:13.231127 #7] DEBUG -- :    (51585.2ms)  UPDATE tmp_reporting_sales_ia SET reporting_license_type = NULL, reporting_residency = 'N';
=> nil
```

If I do create a stored procedure for this exact statement and then call *that* via the ActiveRecord connection, it again runs in under 5 seconds.

```
irb(main):024:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CALL reset_reporting_sales();")
D, [2022-12-07T22:25:06.252457 #7] DEBUG -- :    (4297.1ms)  CALL reset_reporting_sales();
=> nil
```

This is just one basic example, but I'm seeing the same issue with many other statements of higher complexity. I'd really rather not have to deal with the stored procedures until everything is nailed down.

Can anyone explain what Rails overhead is causing the execution of this and other statements via the ActiveRecord connection to take 10 times as long?

Comment: I'd enable the slow query log in MySQL to get an accurate measure of the execution time. That only measures lock time and execute time, which eliminates any overhead due to client code or network latency. This is just to confirm whether the query is actually running differently in the MySQL Server, or if the extra elapsed time you're seeing is due to the client.

Comment: First, updating a million rows at once implies poor schema design.  Let's discuss alternatives where you can avoid the action completely or mostly.  Please describe the data flow that requires this `UPDATE`.

Comment: An `UPDATE` takes longer if more rows actually need changing.  That is, running the _equivalent_ `UPDATE` twice will be faster the second time.  It's not just the mechanism by which you performed the query.

Comment: @RickJames I believe the difference was as you mentioned, that generally in my tests the data was already updated in the second run. Dopey me, poor test design/analysis. I appreciate the insight. As to the process flow, it is too much to describe here, and not relevant to this question, but I would welcome your input, if you have time. I will touch base via email.